# Error: Module unable to decode valid JSON on stdin. Unable to figure out what parameters were passed

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to write a new ansible module in python.

Playbook:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - name: db_configurator
      db_configurator: global_rpm='Test' user_home=/users/xpiwrk1/swjain

Module code:
    #    Initializing the module here which takes as input the required parameters from the playbook. 
    module = AnsibleModule(argument_spec=dict(
       global_rpm=dict(default=None),
       user_home=dict(default=None),
       ), 
       supports_check_mode=True)

    global_rpm = module.params['global_rpm']
    user_home = module.params['user_home']
```

The module is working absolutely fine when I'm running the module directly with python executable giving the input in required json parameters as command line args.

```
python db_configurator.py '{"ANSIBLE_MODULE_ARGS": {    "global_rpm": "core.abp.amdocs.test:test_rpm",    "user_home": "/users/xpiwrk1/swjain" }}'
```

However while running through playbook everytime I'm getting the below error. Anyone having any idea?

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "Error: Module unable to decode valid JSON on stdin.  Unable to figure out what parameters were passed"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After comparison to some other modules with similar functionality. I found out the problem was with the way I imported AnsibleModule.

Replaced

```
AnsibleModule = ansible.module_utils.basic.AnsibleModule
```

with

```
from ansible.module_utils.basic import *
```

And module seems to work fine after this, but still, in some of the forums, I read that this way of importing (from ansible.module_utils.basic import *) is deprecated. Though it solved my problem for now, I'm unsure what the permanent fix should be.